# Is there a way to retrieve a table column name based on cell value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to retrieve column name based on cell value in SQL Server 2016?

Below is the table structure

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
N     Y     N     Y
```

I need column names where value = N i.e output should be Col1, Col3

Comment: Why would `N'Col2'` and `N'Col4'` be returned, when they have a value of `'Y'` not `'N'` and you want columns which have the value `'N'`?

Comment: Add some more rows of sample data, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: Corrected the required output

Comment: Where all values =N ? or is it at least one value =N?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be explicit in the SQL.  Something like this:

```
select 'Col1' as col from t where col1 = 'N' union all
select 'Col2' as col from t where col2 = 'N' union all
select 'Col3' as col from t where col3 = 'N' union all
select 'Col4' as col from t where col4 = 'N';
```

Or:

```
select v.col
from t cross apply
     (values ('col1', col1), ('col2', col2), ('col3', col3), ('col4', col4)
     ) v(col, val)
where val = 'N';
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a `VALUES` table construct here to unpivot the data:

```sql
SELECT V.ColName
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(N'Col1',Col1),
                        (N'Col2',Col2),
                        (N'Col3',Col3),
                        (N'Col4',Col4))V(ColName,ColValue)
WHERE V.ColValue = 'N';
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you are looking for is a comma separated list of column names that satisfy your condition for every row. If I got that right, I think you want

```
select replace(rtrim(concat (nullif(case when col1='N' then 'col1 ' end, ''),
                             nullif(case when col2='N' then 'col2 ' end, ''),
                             nullif(case when col3='N' then 'col3 ' end, ''),
                             nullif(case when col4='N' then 'col4 ' end, ''))),' ',',')
from your_table;
```

**Note** that this returns an empty string if all 4 columns have null values.

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=841b75df6d0923eaa91eb7f87cd5783e)

Comment: Yes, I am looking for comma separated column names. But concat_ws() is not recognized in SQL server 2016

Comment: @shiva Try now. The solution gets a bit uglier, but if you can settle for a space instead of comma, you can actually get rid of the replace.

Comment: Thanks @Phil Coulson, more or less I have done same thing to work it out.                                                                          select case when col1='N' then 'col1' + ',' else '' end + 
            case when col2='N' then 'col2'+',' else '' end + ........

Comment: @shiva Note that if ANY of the columns are null, your code will return null